# Java: f21.Person@373ee92

Tags: java, tostring

f21.Person1@373ee92

Ok the f21 represents the package.
Person the class type.

Can anyone explain in simple terms WHY there is an "@" followed by random characters. And what the random chars stand for (position in the memory?).

I receive this when I do the following and HAVEN't declared a toString() method:

```
System.out.println(myObject);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont Override the toString() method in your class, Object class's toString() will be invoked.

```
System.out.println(myObject);// this will call toString() by default.
```

Below is the **Implementation** of toString from **[java.Lang.Object](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html)** class.

> ```
>        The {@code toString} method for class {@code Object}
>        returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the
>        object is an instance, the at-sign character `{@code @}', and
>        the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the
>        object
> ```

```
 public String toString() {
   return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
  }
```

so, apply the same to`21.Person@373ee92`:

21.Person(Fully qualified classname) + @ + 37ee92(hex version of the hasgcode)

Answer (score 0):

It invokes toString() implementation, if you haven't overriden this method then it will invoke `Object`'s version which is implemented as follows

```
  public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
  }
```

It is hex version of hashcode of that instance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't override the `toString()` method, the one provided by `Object` is used. It does [the following](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@`, and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

The "random" characters are the hash code of your object, in hex.